# How can I extract field names from SQL with Perl?

Tags: sql, regex, perl

I have a series of select statements in a text file and I need to extract the field names from each select query. This would be easy if some of the fields didn't use nested functions like `to_char()` etc.

Given select statement fields that could have several nested parenthese like:

`ltrim(rtrim(to_char(base_field_name, format))) renamed_field_name,`

Or the simple case of just `base_field_name` as a field, what would the regex look like in Perl?

Comment: Just 9 minutes ago you posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174015/recursive-nested-expression-in-python ... Can't you make up your mind which language to use?

Comment: Also, you forgot to change the body of the question. It still says Python.

Comment: For obvious reasons, if it's a lot more effort to code it up in one language, it makes sense to switch to another language for this specific case.

Comment: -1 just changing Python to Perl doesn't make your (hard to read and unformatted) code examples valid. I'm pretty sure those aren't even valid in Python.

Comment: @TheObserver - The answer you got from Alex Martelli was not "Python regexes aren't suitable for nested structures," it was "Regexes aren't suitable for nested structures." What makes you think you'd get different answers asking about the same tool in a different language? It _can_ be done in Perl, but it _can_ be done in Python or Ruby or PHP or C#. It's just a terrible idea to try to do so, and it will cause a huge headache. If you need a complex parser, write a parser. Don't keep asking "How do I hammer in this screw?"

Comment: Because different different languages have different strengths and libraries already written for them. If I wanted to write lots of set up code for this problem, why would I pick a dynamic language, why not give myself more work and code in Java or C?

Comment: @TheObserver: The `problem` lies in the approach, not the language. Nested structures are hard to do in RegEx (that's a language, too btw). If you can, try to work towards more easily parsable input as hard as you can. (I didn't, the experience sucked)

Comment: Disagree with Chris Lutz; it's a not very good idea, not a terrible idea, and if it truly is a one-off (you don't always know for certain, even if you think you do) it won't cause a huge headache.  Nevertheless, using an already available sql parser is better.

Comment: +1. Looks to me like a fine question. The original asked whether it was possible to use regular expressions, rather than presuming it was the right tool for the job. The only problem with the question was that it was copied straight from another question under a different language. Kudos to Brian for going ahead and making such a simple fix to an otherwise good question.

Answer (score 11):

Don't try to write a regex parser (though perl regexes *can* handle nested patterns like that), use [SQL::Statement::Structure](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SQL::Statement::Structure).

Comment: +1 for SQL::Statement and friends.  While it can't handle every extreme of contorted SQL, it is at least the right kind of tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ask the target database itself how it would interpret the queries?

In perl, one can use the [DBI](http://dbi.perl.og/) to query the prepared representation of a SQL query.  Sometimes this is database-specific:  some drivers (under the perl `DBD::` namespace) support their RDBMS' idea of *describing* statements in ways analogous to the RDBMS' native C or C++ API.

It can be done generically, however, as the DBI will put the names of result columns in the statement handle attribute `NAME`.  The following, for example, has a good chance of working on any DBI-supported RDBMS:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

use constant DSN => 'dbi:YouHaveNotToldUs:dbname=we_do_not_know';

my $dbh = DBI->connect(DSN, ..., { RaiseError => 1 });

my $sth;
while (<>) {
  next unless /^SELECT/i;   # SELECTs only, assume whole query on one line
  chomp;
  my $sql = /\bWHERE\b/i ? "$_ AND 1=0" : "$_ WHERE 1=0"; # XXX ugly!
  eval {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);  # some drivers don't know column names
    $sth->execute();             # until after a successful execute()
  };
  print $@, next if $@;  # oops, problem with that one
  print join(', ', @{$sth->{NAME}}), "\n";
}
```

The *XXX ugly!* bit there tries to append an always-false condition on the SELECT, so that the SQL engine doesn't have to do any real work when you `execute()`.  It's a terribly naive approach -- that `/\bWHERE\b/i` test is no more correctly identifying a SQL WHERE clause than simple regexes correctly parse out SELECT field names -- but it is likely to work.

Comment: Why not? Because the world isn't ideal and neither is life. I only have access to the data output (sans headers) and the SQL query used to generate the output.

Answer (score 1):

In a somewhat related problem at the office I used:

```
my @SqlKeyWordList = qw/select from where .../; # (1)

my @Candidates =split(/\s/,$SqlSelectQuery);      # (2)

my %FieldHash;                                  # (3)
for my $Word (@Candidates)  { 
   next if grep($word,@SqlKeyWordList);
   $FieldHash($Word)++;
}
```

Comments:

1. SqlKeyWordList contains all the SQL keywords that are potentially in the SQL statement (we use MySQL, there are many SQL dialiects, choosing/building this list is work, look at my comments below!). If someone decided to use a keyword as a field name, you will need a regex after all (beter to refactor the code).
2. Split the SQL statement into a list of words, this is the trickiest part and WILL REQUIRE tweeking. For now it uses Perl notion of "space" (=not in word) to split. 
   Splitting the field list (select a,b,c) and the "from" portion of the SQL might be advisabel here, depends on your SQL statements.
3. %MyFieldHash will contain one entry per select field (and gunk, until you validated your SqlKeyWorkList and the regex in (2)

### Beware

- there is nothing in this code that could not be done in Python.
- your life would be much easier if you can influence the creation of said SQL statements. (e.g. make sure each field is written to a comment)
- there are so many things that can/will go wrong in this parsing approach, you really should sidestep the issue entirely, by changing the process (saves time in the long run).
- this is the regex we use at the office

```
   my @Candidates=split(/[\s
                  \(
                  \)
                  \+
                  \,
                  \*
                 \/
                  \-
                  \n
                  \
                  \=
                  \r
                 ]+/,$SqlSelectQuery
               );
```

Comment: clever, if fragile.  `select 42 'let x=x'` breaks it two ways.

Comment: @ysth: (s)he who writes that, deserves what (s)he gets (and then some)

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting each line into terms (replace every parenthesis, comma and space with a newline), then sorting:

```
perl -ne's/[(), ]/\n/g; print' < textfile | sort -u
```

You'll end up with a lot of content like:

```
fieldname1
fieldname1
formatstring
ltrim
rtrim
t_char
```